# How to pin the console to main window

Tags: eclipse

I am having a problem in eclipse where the console has been separated from the text editor window and has become its own window. I have looked in the eclipse help, where it says to simply drag and drop it back  in, but this is not working. How would I pin it so that it has the same behaviors as the package explorer or outline? I am using Eclipse Luna.

Comment: Can you post screenshots? Ideally, dragging and dropping should've worked.

Comment: @BruceWayne not at the moment, as I am using the app and am away from my laptop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just opened Eclipse Luna and this is the screenshot before I moved the console tab from its default position:

[image: Editor with console in place]

This is the screenshot once I dragged it out of place into its own separate window:

[image]

All you need to do now to put it back in place is this:

- Click the the **tab where it says Console**
- **Drag** it to your target location (say next to the Project Explorer tab) until **you see a gray vertical line** at the point where you're trying to drop it.
- Drop it i.e. let go of the mouse.

Comment: For some reason this worked, as opposed to the dragging and dropping I was doing before.

Comment: @SomeRandomGuy, I'm glad it did.

Comment: doesnt work in eclipse ubuntu as of 2016/05. I'm lost. (meaning, I accidentally dragged the console out of its normal position, and now I just cant get it back where it belongs)

Answer (score 4):

Click on were it says Console and Drag it back onto Eclipse:

[image]